# C++, why is forward declaration not required in structs/classes

Tags: c++

In C++, why does the following compile:

```
struct test {
    void foo() { this->bar++; }
    int bar;
};
```

But not the following:

```
void foo() { bar++; }
int bar;
```

To be clear, I do understand that in the second case `foo` lacks a forward declaration of `bar` and does not compile. I however do not understand why the first one does not fail for the same reason.

Comment: You can think of it as if the inline function bodies are compiled after the end of the class definition is reached

Comment: @BaummitAugen: your answer is fair enough. I suppose what I expected was a reasonable explanation as to why the standard would make an exception for structs/classes.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the expectation is to find out why the standard says so - what underlying principles or reasoning make this a sensible decision? I mean a Q/A like "Why do waves with longer wavelengths diffract more easily? Because physics says so." is technically correct, and also utterly useless.

Comment: @immibis For physics, anyone with sufficient domain knowledge can come to a definite answer, at least as far a human knowledge goes. For old C++ stuff like this, the only definite answer would be Stroustrup's reasoning from back in the day. That makes *one* person that can provide a definite answer, unless you happen to find some quote that covers exactly that. That's quite a significant difference IMO.

Comment: @BaummitAugen If there is a good reason then undoubtedly other people will have come across it too. A lot of language rules (especially in C and C++) are either because it was easier to implement the compiler that way, or because it was impractical to write code the other way. A lot of standards (but maybe not C++) also provide justifications for their arcane rules.

Comment: @immibis You may find a good reason, but how would you know if it it *the* reason? I mean, don't get me wrong, I don't fundamentally hate questions like this (didn't even cast any vote against it as you can see), and some do have definite answers (especially when talking about newer features with their proposal paper trail), but for the early, non-"C-heritage" stuff in particular, I just honestly don't understand what people expect to hear beyond "Standard says so" or speculation.

Answer (score 2):

In  case of a structure, scope of the member variable is available within the structure. So if you define a function within a structure that variable will be available within the function.

But that is the not the case in second scenario.